# Python - How to run section of code depending on parameters

Tags: python

I am new in Python script. I would like to be a bit pro in my code writing. Basically, I have a script that has a functionally and I would like to add new functionality.

my code looks a bit like:

```
const declaration
CONST1 = ....
CONST2 = ....
CONST3 = ....
CONST4 = ....
CONST5 = ....
CONST6 = ....
CONST7 = ....


function declaration
def f1:
    ....

def f2:
    ....
def f3:
    ....
def f5:
    ....
def f7:
    ....
def f8:
    ....
def f0:
    ....

first part 
logic
logic
logic
logic
logic
logic
logic
    logic


second part 
.......
.......
```

I want to add new functionality down here, so that when the script runs with certain params, the first parts or second runs depending on params.

I know I could use `if ... else` to do this, but would like to know if there is a more professional way to do this. so that the code would be more maintainable and easy to add things. Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Put them into functions and call the right one depending on your parameters

Comment: You are asking how to do `control flow` this is a very broad question, depending on your data/size of application, you can use different approaches out of loads of possibilities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should to use `dictionary`

for example:

```
CONST1 = 'CONST1'
CONST2 = 'CONST2'

def f1():
    return 'Hello from f1 function'

def f2():
    return "Hello from f2 function"

my_data = {
    'CONST1': f1,
    'CONST2': f2,
}

def run(key):
    # If there is no key, just return message
    # Or use try/catch
    if key not in my_data.keys():
        return 'Oops, I can\'t find the key'

    # Here we get a value via key, and call function via parentheses
    return my_data[key]()

print(run('CONST1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of Python Dictionary.

```
def f(x):
    return {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
    }.get(x, 9)    # 9 is default if x not found
```

or

```
options = {
    0 : First,
    1 : Second,
}
options[num]()
```